# Body Talk pt. 1

Tags: riddle

A very deep well

Full of swords, knives and daggers

All these within you

**Hint**

> Really a body part

Comment: Is this a mouth? Deep well meaning from the mouth down to the stomach, the swords, knives, daggers are teeth because they are sharp.

Comment: Two for Two. You go Glenn Coco, erm, @Takeshi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is

> A mouth

A very deep well

> Means the digestive track from the mouth to the stomach

Full of swords, knives and daggers

> Means the teeth because they are sharp and can cut through like swords, knives and daggers.

All these within you

> With 'these', meant the line before, which are teeth.